# How do you import dir from './directory'?

Tags: javascript, import

```
import middlewares from './middlewares';
import routes from './routes';
```

Someone made this work in their [project](https://github.com/gocreating/express-react-hmr-boilerplate/blob/dev/src/server/app.js). But, when I try to do the same in my project, it doesn't work. The ./middlewares got an error "cannot resolve file 'middlewares'". How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
import middlewares from './middlewares';
```

Will import the file "index.js" in the directory "./middlewares", or throw an error if no such file is found.

In your example, it's precisely "./middleware/index.js" that in turn [imports more files in the same folder](https://github.com/gocreating/express-react-hmr-boilerplate/blob/dev/src/server/middlewares/index.js).